# Option page's form doesn't work

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-options

I have two option pages: `General Options > MyOptionPage1` and `CustomPostType > MyOptionPage2`

Both have a form, but the after clicking `Save` in second option page I land in the 404 page.

Here is my code (file `customposttype-options.php` included in my plugin) :

```
<?php
function customposttype_options_menu()
{
    add_submenu_page( "edit.php?post_type=customposttype", "Impostazioni customposttype", "Impostazioni customposttype", "manage_options", "impostazioni_customposttype_page", 'customposttype_options');
}
function customposttype_options()
{
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Impostazioni customposttype</h2>

        <form method="post" action="customposttype-options.php">
            <?php settings_fields( 'impostazioni_customposttype' ); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections( 'impostazioni_customposttype' ); ?>



            <label for="colore_sfondo">Colore sfondo</label>
            <input type="text" id="colore_sfondo" name="colore_sfondo" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('colore_sfondo') ); ?>">

            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function register_customposttype_options() { // whitelist options
    register_setting("impostazioni_customposttype", "colore_sfondo");
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'customposttype_options_menu' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_customposttype_options');
```

I've tried to change the `action` attribute of the form but nothing changed (`action=""`, no action, `admin_url('customposttype-options.php')`, ...).
The first working option page is exactly the same but with namespace changed (so, `settings_fields( 'impostazioni_generaloptions' );`).

Comment: action should definitely not be `customposttype-options.php` ... `action=""`  or no action should work as it posts back to the same page that way. what is the address bar URL of the page. you could try using that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try just using option.php?

`<form method="post" action="options.php">`

Comment: Your solution saves the data, but Wordpress doesn't show me `Options saved successfully `. Any idea?

Comment: Try `<?php settings_errors( 'impostazioni_customposttype' ) ?>` right after your `<h2>`

Comment: It doesn't show me `Options saved successfully` but it's a good practice insert that line.

Comment: I found this from -https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-the-settings-updated-message

`<?php if( isset($_GET['settings-updated']) ) { ?>
    <div id="message" class="updated">
        <p><strong><?php _e('Settings saved.') ?></strong></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: @GregorySchultz I edited your answer, when you accept the edit I'll mark it as accepted.